# Too many indices in array error brian2-python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare an array value with the previous and the next one using the below code but i get the too many indices in array error, which I would like to bypass, but I dont know how.

```
spikes=print(M.V[0])
#iterate in list of M.V[0] with three iterators to find the spikes
for i,x in enumerate(M.V[0]):
    if (i>=1):
        if x[i-1]<x[i] & x[i]>x[i+1] & x[i]>25*mV:
            spikes+=1
print(spikes)
```

and I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-76d7b392071a> in <module>
      3 for i,x in enumerate(M.V[0]):
      4     if (i>=1):
----> 5         if x[i-1]<x[i] & x[i]>x[i+1] & x[i]>25*mV:
      6             spikes+=1
      7 print(spikes)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/brian2/units/fundamentalunits.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1306         single integer or a tuple of integers) retain their unit.
   1307         '''
-> 1308         return Quantity(np.ndarray.__getitem__(self, key), self.dim)
   1309 
   1310     def __getslice__(self, start, end):

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Do note that M.V[0] is an array by itself

Comment: use `and` not `&`. how many elements does `x` have, very unlike that `M.V[0][k]` has k+1 elements

Comment: now I changed my code to  : `spikes=0 print(len(M.V[0])) for i,x in enumerate(M.V[0]): print(i) if (i>=1) and (i<10000): if x[i-1]<x[i] and x[i]>x[i+1] and x[i]>25*mV: spikes+=1 print(spikes)` @rioV8

Comment: I dont know how to create new lines in comments I used <br> and <br/> but nothing happened

Comment: you can always **edit** your question and add en EDIT section. If you don't show the content of `M.V[0]` it is very difficult, show the minimal version that has the error

Answer (score 0):

You said that "M.V[0] is an array by itself". However, you need to say more about it. Probably M is StateMonitor object detailed in https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/recording.html#recording-spikes . Is this correct ?

If so, you need to give full and minimal code in order to understand your details. For instance, what is your neuron model inside NeuronGroup object? More importantly, instead of finding spike event on your own, why don't you use SpikeMonitor class which extremely ease what you are planning ? 
SpikeMonitor class in Brian2 : https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/brian2.monitors.spikemonitor.SpikeMonitor.html